# Struggling to understand use of strcmp and strcpy in word sort

Tags: c

**Instructions for the Code**

You are given a skeleton C program that will sort the input strings (char array) in alphabetical order. The program will first read the number of input n. Then, a for loop will loop n times to read the input string one by one. Finally, it will print the sorted inputs in alphabetical order.

You can assume each word does not contain space and is less than 10 chars, and the total number of input words n is less than 100.

The functionality of reading input and printing words have been done for you. Complete the program by adding the functionality of sorting words.

Hints: 1. For sorting, you should be familiar with Bubble sort. Right? However, here we are swapping the content of two strings instead of integers. 1. As this is a C program, you are unable to use comparators or do assignments for strings like str1 > str2 or str1 = str2 in C++. You have to consider to use the functions in the <string.h> library such as strcmp(), strcpy(), etc...

Example

Input (Assume we want to input 5 words)

```
5
delta
alfa
apple
charlie
bravo
```

Output (Note that "apple" is placed after "alfa" as "p" is after "l" in alphabetical order.)

```
alfa
apple
bravo
charlie
delta
```

**Description of my Question**

Is it possible to explain the lines of code in the solution? I do not understand the following:

1. how do the nested for loops help in sorting the words.
2. how do the lines involving strcpy and strcmp help in sorting words
3. why do we denote a `*` in char `*t`

Please refer to the following code. I have labelled the parts I do not understand with the format: `//Cannot understand: XXXXXXXXXX`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    // Declare a 2D char array to stores inputs words
    // Maximum 100 input words and each word maximum 10 chars
    char words[100][10];
    char temp[10];
    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%s", words[i]);
    }

    // Add codes here to sort words
    int i, j;
    char *t; //Cannot understand: why *t? What is the use of * here?
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++){ //Cannot understand: why use double for loop here?
            if (strcmp(words[j],words[j + 1])>0) { //Cannot understand: FROM HERE
                strcpy(temp, words[j]);
                strcpy(words[j], words[j+1]);
                strcpy(words[j+1], temp); //Cannot understand: TO HERE. How do these lines of strcmp and strcpy help in sorting words?
               }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", words[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since `t` is unused (according to my GCC compiler, and a visual check confirms that `t` is never used), there is no purpose to the variable at all — except perhaps to confuse.

Comment: The code is not well written.  There are no fewer than three distinct variables `i` in the function.  The nested `for` loops should use `for (int i = 0; …)` and `for (int j = 0; …)` and the `int i, j;` line should be deleted.  I'm not convinced that `j` should start from `0` either — `i + 1` would probably be better.

Comment: As for the `strcmp()` comparison, that returns a positive value if the first string compares greater than the second, so if the condition is true, the two strings `word[i]` and `words[j]` need to be swapped.  Strings have to copied around using `strcpy()`, and swapping two variable `x` and `y` needs an extra variable to achieve the swap: `t = x; x - y; y = t;`.  The `strcpy()` calls achieve the same result for `words[j]` and `words[j+1]` using `temp` for the intermediate (`t`) value.

Comment: **"*I'm not convinced that ```j``` should start from ``0`` either — ```i + 1``` would probably be better.**"* Is it okay to explain more on this part please? I don't know why ``j`` cannot start from ``0``

Comment: I withdraw the "I'm not convinced" comment.  The algorithm is O(N²).  I think it is wasteful, but I reserve judgement on the fix.  Using the standard library `qsort()` function would be a good step in the right direction, but it requires different support code (an appropriate comparison function).  With minor tweaks, the code as written seems to work.  I didn't say it worked efficiently.

Comment: Do you mind using a simpler function as I am quite an intermediate beginner? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you need to sort in C, you should reach for the `qsort()` function. It can sort an array or allocated block of memory containing any type of object. You simply write a compare function that is passed as the last parameter of `qsort()` telling it how you want the data sorted.

Writing the `compare()` function is simple, it has the declaration of:

```c
int compare (const void *a, const void *b);
```

Where `a` and `b` are just pointers to the elements in your array. So what is the element type? In you question they would be arrays of `char[10]`. So what does that make `a` and `b` in `compare()`? Pointer to array of `char[10]`, or formally `char (*)[10]`.

So your job inside `compare()` in order to use `a` and `b` is simply to cast each to `char (*)[10]` and then dereference so you are dealing with the original word in array type `char[10]`.

```c
  /* a & b are pointers to adjacent arrays in words, (pointers to char[10]) */
  const char *sa = *(const char(*)[10])a,
             *sb = *(const char(*)[10])b;
```

Now `sa` and `sb` and pointers to the strings that need to be compared. To compare them, you simply loop over the characters until you find the first character between the two that differs (or you reach the end of one of the strings) and your return an `int` of `< 0` if `a` sorts before `b`, or `> 0` if `b` sorts before `a` or `0` if there were no differences between the words.

The full compare could be written as:

```c
#define MAXC  32  /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
...

/* qsort compare function lexagraphically sorts words */
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
  /* a & b are pointers to adjacent arrays in words, (pointers to char[MAXC]) */
  const char *sa = *(const char(*)[MAXC])a,
             *sb = *(const char(*)[MAXC])b;
  
  /* loop advancing a character in each word per-iteration */
  for (;; sa++, sb++) {
    /* if end of either string or characters differ */
    if (*sa != *sb || !*sa)
      break;
  }
  
  return (*sa > *sb) - (*sa < *sb);   /* return sort order */
}
```

Now all you need to do is fill the `words` array with your input strings and then pass the array to `qsort()`, e.g.

```c
  qsort (words, n, sizeof *words, compare);   /* sort array using compare */
```

That's it, that's all that is necessary to fully sort the words in `words`.

When you read the words from the file, you should recognize there is no need to store the number in the first line. Simply read the line with `fgets()` and discard it. Then using `fgets()` read each subsequent line (trimming the `'\n'` character from the end) and increment a counter that you will use to protect your array bounds as well as it telling you how many words were read.

A short example (that increases the number of characters available for each word to `32`, `10` is too short), sorts and then outputs the sorted words could be written as:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC  32  /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXW 100

/* qsort compare function lexagraphically sorts words */
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
  /* a & b are pointers to adjacent arrays in words, (pointers to char[MAXC]) */
  const char *sa = *(const char(*)[MAXC])a,
             *sb = *(const char(*)[MAXC])b;
  
  /* loop advancing a character in each word per-iteration */
  for (;; sa++, sb++) {
    /* if end of either string or characters differ */
    if (*sa != *sb || !*sa)
      break;
  }
  
  return (*sa > *sb) - (*sa < *sb);   /* return sort order */
}

void prnwords (char(*arr)[MAXC], size_t n)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf ("  %s\n", arr[i]);
  }
}

int main (void)
{
  char words[MAXW][MAXC] = {""};
  size_t n = 0;
  
  /* read initial line containing number (discard) */
  if (!fgets (words[n], sizeof words[n], stdin))
    return 1;

  /* read each line storing word in words until EOF or array full */
  while (n < MAXW && fgets (words[n], sizeof words[n], stdin)) {
    words[n][strcspn(words[n], "\n")] = 0;  /* trim \n from word */
    n++;    /* increment counter */
  }
  
  qsort (words, n, sizeof *words, compare);   /* sort array using compare */
  
  puts ("\nsorted words:");   /* output sorted list of words */
  prnwords (words, n);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Sending your data to the program on `stdin` using a *heredoc*, you could do:

```
$ ./bin/qsort2dwords << 'eof'
> 5
> alfred
> delta
> alfa
> apple
> charlie
> bravo
> alamo
> eof

sorted words:
  alamo
  alfa
  alfred
  apple
  bravo
  charlie
  delta
```

This approach will be much more efficient (and much more well tested) than you trying to invent your own sort